# self.collectionView nil yet methods are passed a valid reference

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, xib

I've built a project with a UICollectionViewController and UICollectionView in a UISplitViewController as per this screen grab:

[image: Xib file]

The problem I have is that when I refer to `self.collectionView` in any of the UICollectionViewController methods, I get a `nil`. But if I examine the `collectionView` argument in any of the datasource or delegate methods, it refers to the collection view. `self.view` also refers to the UICollectionView correctly.

I've tried to rebuild the xib and everything else I can think of, but I cannot get `self.collectionView` to return the collection view referred to by `self.view`.

Anyone got any ideas what the problem might be?

Comment: Did you make an outlet for the collectionView?

Comment: Which methods specifically are you referring to when you say "any of the `UICollectionViewController` methods"?

Comment: @jervine10 You shouldn't have to make an outlet for the collectionView if you're using `UICollectionViewController`.

Comment: The UICollectionViewController has a collectionView property that appears to work the same way as the tableView property on a UITableViewController. At least according to the dock. I checked a xib containing a table view and there was no outlet for the tableView on the UITableViewController. So both the tableView and collectionView property appear to be dynamic ones for the matching views. "Any of the UICollectionViewController methods" means any method on my class. At no point is the collectionView property returning a non-nil result.

Comment: How are you changing the default `UIViewController` in the `UISplitViewController` to a `UICollectionViewController`?

Comment: Not changing it at all. The xib is creating the structure and everything appears correctly and works. It's just this one thing that is strange. Could be a bug :-(

Comment: Have you subclassed `UICollectionViewController`? When you say "my class" are we talking about an instance of your subclass, or something else?